# Can we use the radian formula when angles in triangle are small?

Tags: differential-geometry

[image]
If there is a very small angle $d\theta$,then $R$ is approximately equal to $y$ as they get closer(This approximation should get better and better as $d\theta$ gets smaller and smaller),since $R$ and $y$ are equal,they can be considered as radius of a circle,so is
$y\times d\theta=R\times d\theta=x$?

Comment: You have $x=R\sin d\theta,\,y=R\cos d\theta$, or at leading order $x=Rd\theta,\,y=R$.